# How to catch an "Failed Binder Transition"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

I try to build a workaround, if my code fails to put my image arraylist as extra to the next Activity. Therefore I need to catch the "FAILED BINDER TRANSITION" in any kind to procede with another code.

Here is my code:

```
boolean canParsePictures = true;

intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLICKED_PICTURE_INDEX, position);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
try {

    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_PICTURES, pictures);// here
    startActivity(intent); // or here is the failed binder transition thrown 

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    canParsePictures = false;
    Log.d("ContentFragment", "Failed to put Pictures");
}
if (!canParsePictures) {
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_ITEMPICTURE_DEPENDENCIES, itemPictureDependencies);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The catch clause in this code is not called and the activity doesn´t open.

I don´t want to compress my images, because in the next activity they are shown in a detail view. I don´t want to save them to an file, because i´ve stored the images in an database. I want the images to get load in the next activty just as compromise solution.

Comment: That is a secondary error, fix the original problem from which it results instead.

Comment: I think the error is caused, because i parse too much image data inside of the extras. I tried to put just one image and it worked out. Otherwise it would be posible to decide according to the size of the parcablearraylist. Do you have any idea, how i can find out that size?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any idea, how i can find out that size?

You are limited to ~1MB worth of `Intent` extras. Even one image may be too large, depending on where the image comes from (e.g., camera full-resolution photo).

One approach is to maintain an image cache via a singleton, and pass ID references to that cache in your `Intent` extras.